# R: How to use RJDBC to download blob data from oracle database?

Tags: r, oracle, jdbc

Does anyone know of a way to download blob data from an Oracle database using RJDBC package?

When I do something like this:

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC(driverClass=..., classPath=...) 
conn <- dbConnect(drv, ...)

blobdata <- dbGetQuery(conn, "select blobfield from blobtable where id=1")
```

I get this message:

```
Error in .jcall(rp, "I", "fetch", stride) : 
  java.sql.SQLException: Ongeldig kolomtype.: getString not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CBlobAccessor
```

Well, the message is clear, but still I hope there is a way to download blobs. I read something about 'getBinary()' as a way of getting blob information. Can I find a solution in that direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that RJDBC tries to convert the SQL data type it reads to either `double` or `String` in Java. Typically the trick works because JDBC driver for Oracle has routines to convert different data types to String (accessed by `getString()` method of `java.sql.ResultSet` class). For BLOB, though, the `getString()` method has been discontinued from some moment. RJDBC still tries calling it, which results in an error.

I tried digging into the guts of RJDBC to see if I can get it to call proper function for BLOB columns, and apparently the solution requires modification of `fetch` S4 method in this package and also the result-grabbing Java class within the package. I'll try to get this patch to package maintainers. Meanwhile, quick and dirty fix using rJava (assuming `conn` and `q` as in your example):

```
s <- .jcall(conn@jc, "Ljava/sql/Statement;", "createStatement")
r <- .jcall(s, "Ljava/sql/ResultSet;", "executeQuery", q, check=FALSE)
listraws <- list()
col_num <- 1L
i <- 1
while(.jcall(r, 'Z', 'next')){
  listraws[[i]] <- .jcall(r, '[B', 'getBytes', col_num)
  i <- i + 1
}
```

This retrieves list of `raw` vectors in R. The next steps depend on the nature of data - in my application these vectors represent PNG images and can be handled pretty much as file connections by `png` package.

Done using R 3.1.3, RJDBC 0.2-5, Oracle 11-2 and OJDBC driver for JDK >= 1.6

Comment: This sounds brilliant! So I have to run this piece of script right before the dbGetQuery?  I will give it a go as soon as possible.

Comment: When I run this: s <- .jcall(conn, "Ljava/sql/Statement;", "createStatement"), the result is: Error in as.character.default(obj) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector. Are you sure it worked on your machine?

Comment: Sorry, a typo - supposed to be conn@jc. Will make an edit to the answer

Comment: This is actually instead of dbGetQuery; this is very simplified part of what is happening inside it. Should be good for retrieving single BLOB columns though

Comment: @rdatasculptor, can you please provide insights into how to insert an image as a blob in the oracle database using R